# 'nanomsg/nn.h' file not found on MAC

Tags: macos, torch, luarocks, nanomsg

I want to install nn with LuaRocks on macOS. But when running

```
sudo luarocks install nn      //I use sudo because otherwise I don't have permission to install
```

I am getting the error

> lnn.c:4:9: fatal error: 'nanomsg/nn.h' file not found
>   include
>   ^ 1 error generated.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brew comes to the rescue.

Run:

```
brew install nanomsg
```

This worked for me.